# JQuery UI Accordion transition issues with overflow

Tags: css, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion, bootstrap-select

I am using [Bootstrap-Select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) inside a jQuery UI accordion, and in order for it to work properly, I need to style accordion's content as follows:

CSS:

```
.ui-accordion-content {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

The Bootstrap-select works as expected, but it causes the transition between headers to mess up. Without the overflow css, the transition works as expected, but then the Bootstrap-Select breaks..
[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Header Two (Bootstrap-Select)</h3>
  <div>
    <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true">
      <option>Select 1, Option 1</option>
      <option>Select 1, Option 2</option>
      <option>Select 1, Option 3</option>
      <option>Select 1, Option 4</option>
      <option>Select 1, Option 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
  heightStyle: "content"
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ishq786/zgoxjob6/)

Comment: What do you mean the by BS-select breaks. Did you make sure you have data-live-search=true? It seems to be working for me https://jsfiddle.net/zgoxjob6/1/

Comment: @miro Added a picture of what BS-Select looks like when overflow is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `data-container="body"` to the select tag and remove the css overflow. I think this is the result you are looking:

https://jsfiddle.net/hbmjvr7L/